# Installing a pull git request with pip

Tags: pip, django-2.0

This commit seems to have sorted out filtering with Django=>2. How do I install this?

https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/pull/492

It does not seem to be part of the main graphql-python/graphene-django codeset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pull request is not part of `graphql-python/graphene-django` codebase yet; you have to install from the fork `jayhale/graphene-django` containing the commits. Choose the hash of the last commit in the pull request (looks like it's `eafed16a167ffe8991226f224db33e5c8451a44b`, commit message "Remove unsupported python & Django test cases") to install from:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/jayhale/graphene-django@eafed16a167ffe8991226f224db33e5c8451a44b
```